# Direct cylindrical coordinate 3D plots

Tags: plotting

Do we have a variant of `ParametricPlot3D[]` based *directly* on cylindrical parametric coordinates in 3D ? ( We could transform to Cartesian, however...),

as in images by Fei Li:

[FeiLi3D_Polar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894718/examples-of-beautiful-graphics-of-curves-and-surfaces-in-mathbbr3/1897490#1897490://)

Comment: Do you mean to plot $(\rho, \theta, z) = f(u, v)$ (or $f(t)$)?  The term "cylindrical parametric" makes it sound like the cyl. coords. are to be the inputs instead of the outputs, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The latter.  Example is of (since deleted)  images by Fei Li .

Comment: What I had in mind in "the latter" is $w = f(\rho, \theta, z)$, which is not what `RevolutionPlot3D` plots.  The now-accepted answer plots a function of two parameters $z = f(\rho, \theta)$, which might be better described as "polar parametric" instead of cylindrical (i.e. the domain represents polar coordinates).  Whatever the link shows, it would be nice if the question were self-contained.

Comment: Sorry about this all.  RevolutionPlot3D[{ 2 + Cos[5 t/2], Sin[5 t/2]}, {t, 0,  4  Pi}, {\[Theta], t - 0.1 , t + 0.1 }, MaxRecursion -> 4,  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]  is indeed a spiral  (that was not bargained for) !!

Comment: @Narasimham This is why I said "yes and no",  and why I illustrated one of the examples. There's no self contained "`CylindricalPlot[]`", but you can use `RevolutionPlot3D[]` to much the same effect, it's just a question of figuring out exactly how to plot what you're specifically after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.
What you want is `RevolutionPlot3D`

Here is an approximation of the plot using those function values directly:

```
ps = {Orange, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Purple, Magenta};
l = Table[
   RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[17/7 t], 
     Sin[17/7 t]}, {t, -2 Pi + 2 i Pi, 2 i Pi}, {θ, t - 0.025, 
     t + 0.025}, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotStyle -> ps[[i]], 
    Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    Background -> Black], {i, 1, 7}];
Show[l, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: I do not get the same figure with your code, quite odd.

Comment: @Moo If you get slightly different colour configuration, that's because I previously used 8 colours on accident, which caused overlapping, edited the code back to 7, but thought it was a bit redundant to upload new image.

Comment: The shape of the figure I get looks nothing like yours. Using MMA 10.4.1 on Windows.

Comment: Try adding `,ViewPoint -> Top` to the `Show[]` Due to the shape, of the plot it can look kind of funky from different angles.

Comment: Good catch - that was it! Thanks.